# RXJava unsubscribe from the subscribe call

Tags: rx-java

I have the below existing sample code

```
val disposable = Observable.interval(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .take((maxTimeForRequestInSecond / interval).toInt())
                .subscribe {
                    Manager.fetchAvailableSubscriptions(context, params) { status: WebService.Status, response: String? ->
                        if (status == WebService.Status.Success) {
                            // TODO stop the timer and dismiss observable!
                        }
                    }
                }
```

How can i dismiss the Observable when a condition is met from the subscribe like i have on the `TODO`? (i have no access to the `disposable`)

**Note:** Using RxJava `1.1.6`

Answer (score 2):

Your stream is somewhat broken, please express `fetchAvailableSubscriptions` as `Observable<ResponseWithStatus>`. That way you don't have callback in callback and it will easier to implement using operator `takeUntil`

You can do that by wrapping `Manager.fetchAvailableSubscriptions` into `Observable.fromCallable` or `Observable.create`

Then your stream will look more or less like

```
Disposable disposable = Observable.interval(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .take((int)(maxTimeForRequestInSecond / interval))
                .flatMap(__ -> fetchAvailableSubscriptionsObservable())
                .takeUntil(responseWithStatus -> status == WebService.Status.Success)
                .subscribe(responseWithStatus -> {
                         // use the response 
                 });
```